# JSSOR thumbail click event

Tags: jssor

Is there a thumbnail click event for JSSOR?

I want to run some code when a thumbnail is clicked. I looked into EVT_CLICK but it only seems to work with the main slide and not the thumbnails.

Newbie here
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by using .click function. Thanks